# How to create a replicated, multi-node persistent volume with rancher 2

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher-2

I have a rancher setup with 2 worker nodes.

I want to deploy an app with pods distributed between those 2 nodes.

What I am failing to understand is how I can create a local persistent volume that lives in both worker nodes, synchronized so that each of the pods in the worker nodes is able to access files from the volume in its worker node.

I tried using openEBS but for what I read it does not seem to support multi node, longhorn seems to also not support this, and I am failing to understand if I approaching this issue the wrong way, or if indeed there is not yet a supported solution for this.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy solution I'm aware of. Local volume is just that - local. It's up to you how you replicate that, kubernetes does not help with that at all.

You can try and use any replicated filesystem out there, but installing maintaining and integrating them is up to you.

Some options include:

- [gluster](https://www.gluster.org/) / [heketi](https://github.com/heketi/heketi)
- [ceph](https://ceph.io/) / [rook](https://rook.io/)
- [drdb](https://www.linbit.com/drbd/)

They are all a lot of work. Gluster is somewhat better supported on OpenShift.

By the way Amazon EFS does replication for you, but of course it will not be local.